# How to sketch transmission of ht eMZI in frequency domain?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, interferometry

I enrolled in to Optics&Electronics class and this is my homework:

[image: Homework]

There are 5 questions and they were understandable and familiar(Teached in class) but question 3 is something else! I am not familiar with any of these terms. Could any fella who knows optics help me with this?

Comment: I think "ht eMZI" is a typo for "the MZI" (i.e. MZI = Mach-Zehnder interferometer).